# Can you boolean less than compare 2 void * values in C?

Tags: c, void-pointers

I'm qsort()ing some memory pointers in a list to allow a bsearch of them later in a function.  My question is, do I need to type cast those values to something other than const void * to do a legal comparison in C?  I could just do the conversion and let the compiler tell me, but I have a feeling that this might be compiler dependent.

Comment: i don't see any reason it would not work as void* unless you are trying to compare the underlying values. (and from your question it doesn't look like you are.) the things that won't work with a void* are the things that require knowledge of the underlying datatype, so, checking a value, or doing pointer arithmetic.  for what you've described, comparing pointer to pointer, there should be no problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comparisons are fine, arithmetic and dereferencing are not (because you don't know the size of the underlying data). So yes, you can compare void *pointers* quite well <sup>(a)</sup>.

However, keep in mind that you don't usually compare the pointers passed to a `qsort` comparison function, unless you want to sort on their addresses. But, since they'll be sorted in that order already (being an array), there's not much of a use case for that :-)

You generally cast the void pointers to a specific pointer and then compare what they point *to.* Something like:

```
int compfn (const void *p1, const void *p2) {
    const char *str1 = *((const char **)(p1));
    const char *str2 = *((const char **)(p2));
    return strcmp (str1, str2);
}
```

You don't have to create temporaries like `str1` and `str2` (even though any decent compiler would optimise them out anyway). Other than a slight readability issue, there's nothing wrong with:

```
int compfn (const void *p1, const void *p2) {
    return strcmp (*((const char **)(p1)), *((const char **)(p2)));
}
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Subject to the normal rules that the pointers must both point to elements of the same array or one beyond that array - anything else is undefined. I mention that for completeness but, if you're using `qsort`, you'll be working on an array anyway.

Comment: Is there a reason for the return 0 after the return strcmp?

Comment: @Jesus, yes, it was cut and pasted from more complicated code and then (almost) pared down to the simplest form. "Almost" because I missed that bit, which I've now fixed :-)

Comment: Regarding your footnote: equality comparisons (`==` and `!=`) of void pointers are fine, even if they came from different arrays, right?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you want to do something like this in your compare function

```
int compare(const void *a, const void *b) 
{
    int aa = *(int *)a;
    int bb = *(int *)b;
    return aa - bb;
}
```

and convert the void * to the appropriate type (with int's it's just an example).

It is valid to compare to const void * types but this is a comparison of the address. If this is what you want then that's fine if not the above (contrived example) applies (depending on what you're comparing).

EDIT: For your case

```
int compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    if (a < b) return -1;
    else if (a == b) return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

The reason I do it this way is because addresses are sizeof(unsigned long) which is greater than the size of an int which could cause an issue if you overflow the int somehow.

Comment: This will not work, try `char x[4]; compare(x, x+1)` and they will compare as equal (except on a few bizarre systems).

Comment: @Dietrich, this is an example I stated so already.... you would have to do the appropriate comparison....

Comment: It is an example, but that does not change the fact that the cast causes the function to behave incorrectly and is in fact not necessary in the first place, as it is perfectly legal to compare `void *` and the semantics are just as well-defined as they are for other types.

Comment: @Dietrich, yes you can compare them but the point is if you want meaningful comparison you compare the types (unless you're sorting by address).

Comment: @Dietrich It seems highly unlikely to me that anyone would want to sort by memory address for practical purposes

Comment: For example, to remove duplicate object references from a list, sort by memory address then remove duplicates in a linear scan.

Comment: @Dietrich if you need to do that then you should probably consider reworking something else so that doesn't happen rather than trying to do that to fix it.

Comment: Guys, I am sorting by addresses, believe it or not. Thanks for the answers.  Doing some funky memory remapping between pointers so I need to do a sort on actual address values.

Comment: @Michael, then yes comparison should work just fine. Check my edit.

Comment: P.S. On 64-bit Windows system, `sizeof(long) == 4` but `sizeof(void *) == 8`.

Comment: @Dietrich, that's the reason that I made the code do that because of the size discrepancy.